# Rust Book Example: Does dbg! return ownership or not?

Tags: rust

In the Rust official guide chapter 5.2:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let scale = 2;
    let rect1 = Rectangle {
        width: dbg!(30 * scale),
        height: 50,
    };

    dbg!(&rect1);
}
```

> We can put `dbg!` around the expression `30 * scale` and, because `dbg!` returns ownership of the expression’s value,
> the width field will get the same value as if we didn’t have the `dbg!`
> call there. We don’t want `dbg!` to take ownership of `rect1`, so we use a
> reference to `rect1` in the next call.

The guide states that `dbg!` returns ownership of the width expressions value, then right after it says we don't want `dbg!` to take ownership of `rect1` so we use a reference. Why wouldn't `dbg!` return ownership of `rect1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `dbg!` *takes* the ownership and then *returns* it back as a value it evaluates to. It works as something like this function:

```
fn dbg<T: Debug>(val: T) -> T {
    // some debug printing of `val`
    val
}
```

(The real implementation is a little more complex, since it uses the file-line-column information, exact evaluated expression, and works correctly with lifetimes of temporaries)

That is, the value is moved *into* the `dbg!`, but then moved again from `dbg!` into whatever binding you assign it to.

In the first case, therefore, the value of `dbg!` is assigned to the struct field, so this field will be equal to `30 * scale`. The second case, on the other hand, also be written like this:

```
let rect1 = dbg!(rect1);
```

That is, you move the value out of `rect1`, print it, and then store it into new binding, also named `rect1`.

Answer (score 1):

In that second case, it actually takes ownership of what is passed to it, that is, *a reference to `rect1`*, not `rect1`, which it then returns, before instantly discarding it because you are not retrieving it (ie. you are not doing something like `let ref_to_rect1 = dbg!(&rect1);`).